# webpack compile gives ts-loader error on new computer

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack, npm-install, npm-start

I have just set up a new laptop, checked out my sources run npm install as is the norm. Then ran webpack build thus:

npm run clean && npm run scss && webpack --bail --progress --profile

I then get this error which I cannot find details about anywhere. I have dropped node_modules and re-run npm install again but still get the same issue. I am at my wits end... any idea what I can do to solve this?

```
ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/admin/main.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js):
\node_modules\ts-loader\node_modules\micromatch\index.js:44
    let isMatch = picomatch(String(patterns[i]), { ...options, onResult }, true);
                                                   ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at NativeCompileCache._moduleCompile (E:\mydirs\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:240:18)
    at Module._compile (E:\mydirs\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:186:36)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)`
```

I am using typescript 2.7.2, node 6.11.0 and npm 3.10.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I upgraded to node 10, deleted node_modules ran npm install again now it all works fine.